# django-dynamic-formsets not working in one template - the same structure works in other template

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have this simple django template which only displays formset, allows user to add and remove instances of formset, and submittes the data by clicking the button. This templete is fine, it displays all the buttos etc. Here is the code:

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.7.1.min.js' %}"></script>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{profile_form.management_form}}
    <div id="formsets-container">
        {% for form in profile_form %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#formsets-container').formset({
            addText: 'Add strategy',
            deleteText: 'Remove strategy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also have another template, from another project, which is more complex, but the structure of formset is the same, but it doesn't show buttons of adding and removing forms.

Here is the code:

```
{% extends "mainapp/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.7.1.min.js' %}"></script>

<div id="input-div1"></div>
<div class="input-div2">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ simulation_form.initial_amount.label_tag }}
        {{ simulation_form.initial_amount|add_class:"form-control"}}

        {{ simulation_form.number_of_simulations.label_tag }}
        {{ simulation_form.number_of_simulations|add_class:"form-control" }}

        {{ simulation_form.number_of_trades.label_tag }}
        {{ simulation_form.number_of_trades|add_class:"form-control" }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <form method="post" id="myForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{strategy_formset.management_form}}
        <div class="strategy-formset">
            {% for form in strategy_formset %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#strategy-formset').formset({
            addText: 'Add strategy',
            deleteText: 'Remove strategy'
        });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

`simulation_form` is regular form and `strategy_formset` is a formset. As you can see `strategy_formset` is used in the same way as `profile_form` in the first template, but it does not work properly. Could you advise would could be the reason? I attach screenshots of both templates:

[image]

[image]